# PHP: Searching for users that have logged in within the last 15 minutes using Date Diff, etc

Tags: php, date, time, diff

This has been asked before, however I can not for the life of me find it on google or stackoverflow for a solution. I even entered this into my google search: php date("F j, Y, g:i a") date diff.  So, I will ask it here.

I have a date set throughout my whole website that is set like this (done in PHP):

```
  date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');  
$CurLogIn = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

That date then gets SQL Updated into each users lastloginfield to basically check when it was the last time they accessed my page. I wanted to create a page which displays users that have been on a page on my site within the last 15 minutes. However, I cant find a Date Diff Solution for how I set up the time/date above.

Does anyone have a solution for how I can check for all users that have accessed a page within the last 15 minutes using that time format above? Thanks.

Comment: whats' the date field in the databases type?

Comment: I set it as Text. Every Time I use the Date type, it mucks it up.

Comment: dont ever do that, always use a date type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fill in your fields and table name

```
SELECT * from table where NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE <lastloginfield
```

Comment: I tried this. Seems like it should work, but it returned every record in the database. Any reason why it would do that? Most records do not have a time in it yet as some users have not logged in for the first time yet. So the fields are blank. But, still, that shouldn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: its not going to work because you don't use a date type field

Comment: Found the problem.. Its not >. Its supposed to be <lastloginfield. Awesome, it worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: doh, i always do that :-) I assume you change lastloginfield to a date field

Comment: Yes, I did DateTime Type. Otherwise if it were just Date it wouldn't work. Thanks Again Dagon!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly from SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_login) < (60 * 15))
```